# Successful deploy to Tomcat from Grails results in 404 "resource not available"

Tags: tomcat, grails, http-status-code-404, war

I have a simple test Grails 2.5.1 app that runs successfully in dev mode, i.e. `grails run-app`. I did `grails war` and copied the `test1-0.1.war` file to a remote Tomcat8 server, into `tomcat/webapps`, and the autodeploy stuff worked fine. Logs say

```
15-Aug-2015 18:38:33.829 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/test1
15-Aug-2015 18:38:33.892 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/test1 has finished in 63 ms
```

so all looks good. I can see it listed and running under `http://host:8080/manager/html/list` and can click the link to the app, which is `http://host:8080/test1`. At this point I get *"The requested resource is not available."*

If I do a listing of `/opt/tomcat/webapps/test1` I have

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 user user     4096 Aug 15 18:38 test1/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 49511519 Aug 15 18:38 test1-0.1.war
```

and under the second `test1/` you see the start of the actual web app:

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 user user 4096 Aug 15 18:38 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 user user 4096 Aug 15 18:38 ../
drwxr-xr-x 4 user user 4096 Aug 15 18:38 assets/
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Aug 15 18:38 css/
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Aug 15 18:38 images/
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Aug 15 18:38 js/
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Aug 15 18:38 META-INF/
drwxr-xr-x 3 user user 4096 Aug 15 18:38 plugins/
drwxr-xr-x 9 user user 4096 Aug 15 18:38 WEB-INF/
```

The second `test1/` confuses me, but even if I try to go to `http://host:8080/test1/test1` I get the **404** error.

Seems like I might be missing something simple, but I can't figure out what. Any ideas?

(Also, all the servlet/jsp examples are running fine on the server, so I know it's a "healthy" Tomcat instance.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `grails war` or `grails dev war`?

If you ran `grails war` then you deployed a production copy of the application. Check your *grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy* and look at the production database settings. That's the database the app is going to attempt connecting to while running on your remote Tomcat instance. If the database is not available then... you'll have problems.

Also take a look at the logs at *$CATALINA_HOME/libexec/logs/*

Comment: I did `grails war`. Hm, I realized later that I had broken database settings, it could have been that. I tried with an install of tomcat7, and got better log indicatorst, but I'd already removed tomcat8, so... anyway thanks, that *could* have been the issue, and logging simply failed me.

Comment: Ok. I forgot to mention that `grails run-app` uses the development environment by default, in comparison to `grails war` which uses the production environment.